# Searching Polish districts in JSON

Tags: geojson, data, json, poland

I am looking for a map of polish ['powiaty', eng. 'county' or 'district'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powiat) (i.e. second-level unit of local government and administration in Poland, equivalent to a county, district or prefecture) in JSON.

You can find shapefiles here: https://gis-support.pl/granice-administracyjne/. I need a JSON to be able to use it in PowerBI as a custom map.

And possibly if you have some ideas is there any online available repository which offers numerous JSON files for different countries to download?

Comment: Load the shapefiles into QGIS and export as GeoJSON?

Comment: OK, will try that but what I am interested in as well is an online repository of readily available jsons?

Comment: @Mapperz has already mentioned that you can simply achieve the result in QGIS, check this article [QGIS Cropping and Converting shapefiles to TopoJSON format](https://danielcorcoranssql.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/qgis-cropping-and-converting-shp-files-to-topojson-format/). Alternatively check some PowerBI Q&A, e.g. [From Shapefile to TopoJSON for shape map](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/From-Shapefile-to-TopoJSON-for-shape-map/td-p/69691).

Comment: @Mrowkacala, additionally I may refer you to [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you need only the boundary? If yes: https://osm-boundaries.com/.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extract from Shapefiles to GeoJSON available:
[on GitHub pages](https://github.com/ppatrzyk/polska-geojson).

Answer (score -1):

You might use [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) to download that data directly as a GeoJSON, or you might save the data you linked as GeoJSON using QGIS.

Comment: Are there any other repositories that contain .json files of different countries simply ready to download?

Comment: I guess there are.